# Oracle in SSIS package

Tags: oracle

I Create Package in SSIS with sql source Oracle Destination. So I create a table in Oracle that is my Target .
In the Insert Destination How Can I find my table in oracle?

Comment: Have you created a DNS to connect to to Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

Once you create and test your DNS, go to SSIS Data Flow Task and in the Other Destinations double click ADO Net Destination.From the Connection Manager create a new Connection pointing to the DNS you created above. You can see your Oracle tables from the Use a table or View.